# How do i convert a ping variable to int?

Tags: c#, charts, ping

I am trying to process the ping of my PC into a chart, which almost succeeded, but my ping variable does not want to convert to an int

I have tried so many video's and websites on the internet, but i am not succeeding! I made a ping variable and then i tried to convert it onto an int, so i could put it in the chart, but it won't convert!

This is my code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

private void pingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ping ping1 = new Ping();

    PingReply PR = ping1.Send("192.168.2.6");

    Convert.ToInt32(PR);
    chart1.Series["Connection"].Points.AddY(PR);
}
```

I have no compiler errors, but when i start the timer, it crashes and says

> Cannot convert a System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply object to the System.IConvertible type."

Is it even possible to convert it into an int?

Comment: Well, what do you expect the converted value to be? I can´t imagine what a proper conversion from `PingReply` to `int` should do.

Comment: What do you expect to be in your int? the time it took? or....?

Comment: i expect my int to be the amount of ping i have, is that possible?

Comment: What is the amount of a ping? The time needed to send your request and get the answer back? Or the IP-adress? Or ...?

Comment: the amount of ping, I assume you refer to the time in milliseconds between you and the destination. Check fubo's answer and ignore the `/1000` part. A ping in seconds is generally not useful

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`RoundtripTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.roundtriptime) property which holds the roundtrip (send + receive) time in milliseconds.

> Gets the number of milliseconds taken to send an Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo request and receive the corresponding ICMP echo reply message.

```
int milliseconds = (int)PR.RoundtripTime;
```

so your code should look like

```
chart1.Series["Connection"].Points.AddY((int)PR.RoundtripTime);
```

Comment: Thanks! but now i am getting this error "Series data points do not support System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply type values. Only values ​​of the following types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort." on this line: chart1.Series["Connection"].Points.AddY(PR); i don't understand the error, because we already converted the pingreply into an int.

Comment: @DJBeurdex  add the elapsed milliseconds / seconds (`RoundtripTime`) to your chart, not the `RP` object

Comment: i have this code copied, it looks like this:
private void pingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Ping ping1 = new Ping();
            
            PingReply PR = ping1.Send("192.168.2.6");

            int miliseconds = (int)PR.RoundtripTime;



            chart1.Series["Connection"].Points.AddY((int)PR.RoundtripTime);

        }

but i see nothing happening on the form when i start the project, do i have to do anything in the chart?